# How to print the contents of a UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview

In Safari, you can print an entire document -- not merely a screenshot -- but there is no mention in the UIWebView class reference of printing...

Has Apple not provided programmers with a means to do what they do in Safari i.e. print an entire document?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

`[webView viewPrintFormatter]` is the way to go.

Take a look of this tutorial
[How to print the contents of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448059/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-uiwebview?rq=1)